# Constant expression imported from internal npm package is undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have an internal `npm` package which I am using for shared types and constants. I am using typescript with `"target": "ESNext"` and `"module": "NodeNext"`.

In one of my files, I have

```js
export type SupportedLocale = 'en-GB' | 'cy';

export const flagCssValues: Record<SupportedLocale, string> = {
  ['en-GB']: 'fi-gb',
  cy: 'fi-gb-wls'
};
```

But when I publish this package and use `flagCssValues` from my package:

```js
import { flagCssValues } from '@myorg/myfile';
```

and use the value in jasmine tests:

```js
describe('test 01', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('Flag CSS values', flagCssValues);
  });
  ...
});
```

the value of `flagCssValues` comes through as undefined.

I have also tried

```js
const flagCssValues: Record<SupportedLocale, string> = {
  ['en-GB']: 'fi-gb',
  cy: 'fi-gb-wls'
};

export { flagCssValues };
```

with the same results.

The generated JS code is as follows:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.flagCssValues = void 0;
exports.flagCssValues = {
    ['en-GB']: 'fi-gb',
    cy: 'fi-gb-wls'
};
```

Is there a way to export this value correctly?

Comment: What does the compiled JS look like? Also, how are you verifying the values are `undefined`?

Comment: I'm importing the library in jasmine tests: the consumer is an Angular project. The JS is heavily obfuscated.

Comment: Please include the code you're using to verify

Comment: FYI you don't need the square brackets around `'en-GB'`

Comment: I'm just using `console.log('flag CSS values', flagCssValues)` inside jasmine tests.

Comment: The generated JS you're showing is not ESM, so it does not actually export anything when loaded by an ES module. Are your jasmine tests first converted and then run, too, or are those "pure ESM code" and your test file is loading your this generated code?

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- that led me to the solution. I'll post it as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to configure my library and NPM publish pipline with the correct settings. Based on the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/guides/choosing-compiler-options.html#im-writing-a-library), I set `verbatimModuleSyntax` in `tsconfig.json` to `true`. This led to setting `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

The settings that worked correctly are

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  ...
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "...",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.cjs --ext .ts **/*.ts",
    "test:unit": "mocha -p ./test.unit.config.json './test/unit/**/*.test.ts'",
    "test": "npm run test:unit"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.x.x"
  },
  "files": [
    "./lib/**/*.ts",
    "./lib/**/*.js",
    "./lib/**/*.js.map",
    "!./**/*.test.ts",
    "!./**/*.setup.ts"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

**npm-publish.yml**

```yaml
name: Node.js Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run test
      - run: npx tsc
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN}}
```